# AceFem Error in SMTShowMesh

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh, acegen

I consider for a calculation a sphere embedded within a matrix. To plot the results and especially the behavior around the spherical inclusion I want to "cut" through the matrix. That seems to work with "ZoomElements", but in combination with "Domains" to cut only through the inclusion I receive errors.

Below is a minimal sample code:

```
<< AceFEM`;
SMTInputData[];

A = ImplicitRegion[(1. (x))^2 + (1. (y))^2 + (1. (z))^2 > 
    0.1, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}}];

mesh = ToElementMesh[A, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{0., 0., 0.}, 2, 0.0001}, {{0.8, 0.8, 0.8}, 1, 
      0.001}}, MaxCellMeasure -> .1, "MeshOrder" -> 1];

SMTAddDomain[{"Matrix", "MySED3O1DFLEO1DHooke", {}}, {"Inclusion", 
   "MySED3O1DFLEO1DHooke", {}}];
SMTAddMesh[mesh, {{"O1", 1} -> "Matrix", {"O1", 2} -> "Inclusion"}];
SMTAnalysis["Tie" -> True];
```

That is working fine:

```
SMTShowMesh["Mesh" -> True, "BoundaryConditions" -> True, 
 Axes -> True, 
 "ZoomElements" -> ("X" <= 0.55 && ("X" <= 0 || "Y" >= 0) &), 
 AxesLabel -> {"X_1", "X_2", "X_3"}]
```

[image]

That gives errors:

```
SMTShowMesh["Domains" -> "Inclusion", "Mesh" -> True, 
 "BoundaryConditions" -> True, Axes -> True, 
 "ZoomElements" -> ("X" <= 0.55 && ("X" <= 0 || "Y" >= 0) &), 
 AxesLabel -> {"X_1", "X_2", "X_3"}]
```

[image]

Do you have any suggestions or solutions for this problem?

Best,

Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options "Domains" and "ZoomElements" are mutually exclusive. Argument of "ZoomElements" is an "element selector" that can be used to select domains as well. (e.g. element_selector={node_selector, domain_selector} form)

In your case

SMTShowMesh["Mesh" -> True, "BoundaryConditions" -> True,
Axes -> True,
"ZoomElements" -> {("X" <= 0.55 && ("X" <= 0 || "Y" >= 0) &),
"Inclusion"}, AxesLabel -> {"X_1", "X_2", "X_3"}]

Comment: That is an elegant solution. Thank you very much Mr. Korelc.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to do some walkaraound.

First you can identify the nodes in your inclusion and get their coordinates:

```
incluNodes = SMTElementData[SMTFindElements["Inclusion"], "Nodes"];
ninNodes = Dimensions[incluNodes];
xincluNodes = 
  Table[SMTNodeData[incluNodes[[i]], "X"], {i, ninNodes[[1]]}];
```

Then you can select the nodes you are interested in:

```
showINodes = {};
Do[Do[
  If[xincluNodes[[i, j, 1]] <= 0.55,
   If[xincluNodes[[i, j, 1]] <= 0 || xincluNodes[[i, j, 2]] >= 0,
    AppendTo[showINodes, i]];
   Break[]]
  , {j, 4}]
 , {i, ninNodes[[1]]}]
```

And finally you can plot some cross section of your inclusion:

```
SMTShowMesh["Domains" -> "Inclusion", "ZoomNodes" -> DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[incluNodes[[showINodes]]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: that is a very good a workaround. Thank you for that. Does the error message occurs for you too, when you are using the ```"ZoomElements"```command?

Comment: Yes, it occurrs.